# Configuring Angular FileManager for custom use

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am interested in using a great JavaScript-based UI framework for file management called [Angular FileManager](https://github.com/joni2back/angular-filemanager).  You can follow the link to peruse the GitHub page for this project, you can also access a running demo of the framework by clicking [here](http://angular-filemanager.zendelsolutions.com/).

The problem I face is that there appears to be very little documentation or support for configuring this framework for custom use.  Specifically, I would like to modify the file `config.js` to specify my own server-side endpoints for the web services which the file manager uses.  I tried adapting the demo, available at the link, but my browser simply hangs.

Ideally, I would be looking for either a link to a good tutorial on how to configure Angular FileManager *or* a user who has successfully worked with this framework before and has something to say.

Answer (score 1):

you can extend the config doing something like:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //example to override angular-filemanager default config
    angular.module('FileManagerApp').config(['fileManagerConfigProvider', function (fileManagerConfig) {
      var defaults = fileManagerConfig.$get();

      fileManagerConfig.set({
        appName: 'my own angular-filemanager',
        sidebar: false,
        allowedActions: angular.extend(defaults.allowedActions, {
          remove: false,
          copy: false
        })
      });

    }]);
  </script>
```